# Deleting single channel/all channels does not work

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a bot that manages a server to get used to JavaScript and the Discord.js library. I tried deleting a channel using this code, but it didn't work.

```
guild.channel.delete('Making room for new channels')
  .then(deleted => console.log(`Deleted ${deleted.name} to make room for new channels`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

I've already tried to replace the first line with `channel.delete` and `channel.guild.delete`, but I kind of gave up since I have no clue on how to make it delete every channel in the guild.
As bad as this sounds, I'm not trying to destroy any discord server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ensure `guild.channel` is a [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your bot to delete every single channel in a guild, do this:

```
guild.channels.forEach(c => c.delete());
```

Your attempt failed to work since `channel` isn't a property of the [Guild Class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild). So what I'm doing is accessing the `channels` collection of the Guild Class, which contains every single Channel of that Guild. Then we can iterate over each channel and use the `delete` method, which is part of every [GuildChannel Object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel).