# Discord.js - How can I make a command to delete all channels from a server?

Tags: server, discord.js

How can I make a command to delete all channels from a server in Discord js?

I cannot do it, and I need help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll have to iterate over guilds and delete all channels that way, if I understand the question correctly. This site explains how to do that: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel.

Something like: 
`guild.channels.deleteAll()` for a specific guild. That would delete all channels from the guild.

Comment: I'm learning the basics of programming, I still can't do a command alone.

Comment: @iSync I updated the question to include a snippet from the referred documentation.

Comment: I can not understand, what do you mean? What is this message sent?

Comment: How can I do this when I send a message type:
"r!"deletechannels
and all channels will be deleted?

"r!" prefix

Comment: I updated the answer to specify just usage of the guild. I do not have access to the discord.js library, I am only referring to questions I have found online that are related to this issue. Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524990/deleting-single-channel-all-channels-does-not-work and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201440/discord-js-deleting-all-channels-in-a-server

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check if your bot is an admin first.

I would recommend only allowing the guild owner to run the command.

```
message.guild.channels.array().forEach(element => {
    if (element.deletable) {
        element.delete("Wiping channel.");
    }
});
```

[DiscordJS Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/)